# Not able to highlight the input fields if left empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form which gets submitted normally, now I have 2 requirement that needs to be completed on click of submit button, if these requirements are completed then the data needs to get saved in database

> 1) Border of the input  boxes get highlighted if input  boxes are left empty
>
> 2) If the image upload is left empty, a written message below the upload button should appear saying that the image is missing
>
> 3) The form should not get submitted till all input boxes and image upload are filled
>
> 4) Would also appreciate if someone could tell how I can use this code for all input boxes together instead of using separately for each one

Currently when I click on submit button, if the box is empty it highlights the input but after that submits the form also and the image message is also not appearing

Form Code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/add_profile" method="post" >
    <input id="user"  type="text" />
    <input id="pwd" type="text" />
    <input type="file" class="form-control modalcontrol" name="profile_img" id="profile_img" required>
        <span class="fileuploadlabl">Upload</span>
    <div class="login-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" >SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script Code

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

   $(".login-btn").click(function(){
     var user = $("#user").val();
    var pwd = $("#pwd").val();

     if(!user){

       $("#user").addClass("makeRed");
     }
       else
       {
       $("#user").removeClass("makeRed");
       }
  if(!pwd){

       $("#pwd").addClass("makeRed");
     }
       else
       {
       $("#pwd").removeClass("makeRed");
       }     
   });
    $("#user").click(function(){
       $("#user").removeClass("makeRed");

    });
      $("#pwd").click(function(){
        $("#pwd").removeClass("makeRed");

    });
});
</script>
```

CSS Code

```
.makeRed{

  border: 2px solid red !important;

}
```

Comment: I'd use the jquery validate plugin for this because no doubt you'll want to improve the validation later on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply iterate all the `input`s to validate them (*comments inline*)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".login-btn").click(function(){ 
     $( "input, select" ).each( function(){ //iterate all inputs
        var $this = $( this );
        var value = $this.val();
        $this.removeClass( "makeRed" ); //reset the class first
        if ( value.length == 0 )
        {
           $this.addClass( "makeRed" ); //add if input is empty
        }
     });
   });
    $( "input,select" ).focus( function(){
       $( this ).removeClass( "makeRed" ); //on focus of the input remove the markRed class
    })
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".login-btn").click(function() {
    $("input, select").each(function() { //iterate all inputs
      var $this = $(this);
      var value = $this.val();
      $this.removeClass("makeRed"); //reset the class first
      if (value.length == 0) {
        $this.addClass("makeRed"); //add if input is empty
      }
    });
    if ( $(".makeRed").length > 0 )
    {
        alert( "Some validation errors" );
    }
  });
  $("input,select").focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("makeRed"); //on focus of the input remove the markRed class
  })
});
```

```css
.makeRed
{
   border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="user" type="text" />
  <input id="pwd" type="text" />
  <input type="file" class="form-control modalcontrol" name="profile_img" id="profile_img" required>
  <span class="fileuploadlabl">Upload</span>
  <div class="login-btn">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: @gurvinder372 the i/p boxes are getting highlighted but the message for empty file is not coming, and also can you tell how to show this highlighted error for dropdown

Comment: @sammy Check the updates, change the selector to `$( "input, select" )`

Comment: @gurvinder372  the dropdowns didn't got highlighted and file upload message is also not coming

Comment: @sammy I have attached a demo here.

Comment: @gurvinder372  i have applied css to it to make it behave as a button so this required warning is not displayed there, for this reason I want a warning written in form of a message inside a div/span/p. I tried to show the div that contains a warning but some issue is coming with it

Comment: @sammy which warning? There is no warning in your code.

Comment: @gurvinder372  in your code snippet, if we do not upload a file, a message comes saying "please select a file", but in my view this message won't come, so if the user does not upload a file and tries to submit the form, the form won't get submit and he will not get a warning also, to avoid this i want a message

Comment: @sammy I have added the demo for the same

Comment: @gurvinder372  I don't want an alert i want a text displayed below the button inside div/span/p

Comment: @sammy You can try that yourself and post a question if *display a text below button* doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    /**** When you click on input text element - remove class 'makered' -- Start *****/
    $("form input").focus(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('makeRed');
    });
    /**** When you click on input text element - remove class 'makered' -- Ends *****/

    /**** While submit, if form is not valid, add error line and do not allow to submit, else allow submit -- Starts *****/
    $("form").submit(function() { //validate on submit
        var isError = false;
        $(this).find('input').each(function(){
            if(!($(this).val()))
            {
                $(this).addClass('makeRed');
                isError = true;
            }
            else
                $(this).removeClass('makeRed');

        });
        if(isError)
            return false; // do not submit the form
    });
    /**** While submit, if form is not valid, add error line and do not allow to submit, else allow submit -- Ends *****/
```

And remove required attribute from input type file tag.

This will validate your form while submit, not while click, so the better solution instead of validating on click.

Comment: the i/p box are not getting highlighted

Comment: Have you removed 'required' attribute from **input type file** ?